# Socket programming - accept function accepts only 6 requests at a time

Tags: c, sockets

I am trying to build a simple web server. I accept the request using the accept function and put the request in queue. Another thread which is initially at sleep wakes up after 2 min and serves the requests. Till this time, all the request should be queued up in the queue. I have observed that the accept function does not accept more than 6 requests 
I even tried setting `listen(s,10)`

Below is a part of the code where I am binding the socket and accepting connections

```
if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&serv, sizeof(serv)) < 0) {
    perror("bind");
    exit(1);
  }
  if (getsockname(s, (struct sockaddr *) &remote, &len) < 0) {
    perror("getsockname");  
    exit(1);
  }
  listen(s, 10);
  sock = s;
  if (soctype == SOCK_STREAM) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Entering accept() waiting for connection.\n");
    while(1)
    {

      sock = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *) &remote, &len);
      //Accepting the request and adding to to a queue
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please post your code - or even better - a minimized example which exhibits the same behaviour.  http://sscce.org/

Comment: Also, which OS is this? (i.e. which sockets/stack implementation?)

Comment: Assuming this is some flavour of Linux, what does `cat /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn` say?

Comment: What does `echo "#include <sys/socket.h>" | gcc -x c -E -dM - | grep SOMAXCONN` say?

Comment: @DigitalTrauma I am running the code on Ubuntu
The answer to both the command you have given is 128

Comment: what are you doing with len? it is a value-result parameter , so you need to reset it each time IIRC